# Set up git to pull and push all branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch, push

I'd like to push and pull all the branches by default, including the newly created ones.

Is there a setting that I can define for it?

Otherwise, when I add a new branch, locally and I want to pull it from the server, what is the simplest way to do it?

I created a new branch with the same name and tried to pull but it doesn't work. Asks me for all the remote config of the branch. How do I set it.

Comment: "and tried to pull but it doesn't work".  Details please.  Show us what command you tried to use.

Comment: 2023, Git 2.41: [`git push -u --branches`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76284108/6309)

Answer (score 1575, accepted):

The simplest way is to do:

```
git push --all origin
```

This will push tags and branches.

Comment: Among dozens of answers that I found on SO and other places, this is the simplest way to push a newly created local branch, without touching configuration. Thanks!

Comment: And if you add `-u` once, e.g. `git push --all origin -u`, tracking is setup and after that you can simply use `git push`.

Comment: For git version 1.7.12.3 I had to use `git push --tags origin` to push all tags.

Comment: Also look at "--mirror" instead of "--all" this push more stuff

Comment: @Loda - Is "--mirror" going to do what the poster wants?  We had a guy vaporize all branches on the remote repo with "--mirror" (he only had master checked out when he did "--mirror"). I suspect there's a way to fix up your refs/remote/* but didn't have time to play with it and ended up restoring from backup.

Comment: @Scott "--mirror" does more stuff than just pushing news branch. and it does it differently. (ie: force the update, delete old branch, ...). It does more than what the poster asked. Anyway, according to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333102/154272 and https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html, this is probably NOT the best way to go.

Comment: To also push the tags from 1.8.3 on you can use `git push --all --follow-tags origin`

Comment: WARNING: If you have a bunch of LOCAL branches that you have not cleaned up (features, hotfix's) - or did not clean up properly (me), this will flood your remote. Damn. And we just did a pruning. Not sure why my local had so many branches left over.

Comment: It didn't push tags for me.. I had to do `git push --tags origin` as well

Comment: to push all local branches,
git push <remote> --all

Comment: We were trying to move our repo, but only had checked out a couple of the branches. Origin had all the branches. git push --all seems to push only the local branches and not the tracking branches. So I guess you have to checkout all branches before trying to push.

Comment: this doesn't push **all** branches (as OP asked) but only **all local** branches, so for me this doesn't work cause I want to copy **all** branches from one repo to another via local repo, but only master (checkouted) and local branches are pushed

Comment: @vladkras what other branches would you be aiming to push other than local ones?

Comment: @vladkras sorry, I didn't read your comment correctly and now cannot edit.
My response: this is because git is distributed so any commands that you issue are to interact with your *local* set of branches and tags. As you mentioned, you'd have to have all of the branches and tags locally for this command to work. I would say that this is not something that people would do often.

Answer (score 156):

With modern git you **always fetch all branches** (as remote-tracking branches into `refs/remotes/origin/*` namespace, visible with `git branch -r` or `git remote show origin`).

By default (see documentation of `push.default` config variable) you push ***matching branches***, which means that first you have to do `git push origin branch` for git to push it always on `git push`.

If you want to **always push all branches**, you can set up push refspec.  Assuming that the remote is named `origin` you can either use [git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

```
$ git config --add remote.origin.push '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
$ git config --add remote.origin.push '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```

or directly edit `.git/config` file to have something like the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = user@example.com:/srv/git/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
        push  = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
        push  = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Comment: @Merc: `git push --all origin` is good for one time publishing all branches and tags, though default up till current version 'matching' semantic would mean that you would push all branches afterwards... unless you add new branch or tag.  The **setting** to *"push [...] all the branches by default"* is as written.

Comment: You could improve the answer to add the way to reconfigure Git this way. This is useful for users having set the simple mode.

Comment: This has changed since git 2.0. Push default is simple, not matching any more.

Comment: I tried this and got an error on push: `fatal: Invalid refspec ''+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*''` **(Note: I'm on git 2.0. I'm still working out how to fix this.)**

Comment: @BrianLacy it looks to me like you have quotes around the refspec in the configuration. Just open config file in editor and check.

Comment: Now default value for `push.default` is `simple`.

Comment: On my git 1.9.5 git push --all origin does not push all tags. It pushes all branches.

Comment: A separate git push --tags origin is required to push the tags. This can be verified easily as when git push --tags origin is rerun the behaviour is different, saying it is all up to date.

Answer (score 41):

I had used below commands to migrate all branches to the new repository.

```
~$ git clone --mirror <url_of_old_repo>
~$ cd <name_of_old_repo>
~$ git remote add new-origin <url_of_new_repo>
~$ git push new-origin master
~$ git push new-origin --mirror
```

**NOTE**: I had to use second last (i.e. push master first) command while cloning a repo from Atlassian [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/atlassian-stash-enterprise-git-repository-management) to AWS [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) (blank repo). I am not sure the reason, but after pushing (`git push new-origin --mirror`) default branch was referring to some other branch than `master`.

Comment: Perfect for moving a repo to another host. Thank you!

Comment: This is indeed only useful method. Use `git push new_origin --all`just push your current local branches to new_origin, not all branches of origin.

Comment: Just noting that this makes a `--bare` repository, which is a bit different from a regular repository, it only has the `.git` files, not your files. It's perfectly enough if you are not going to do work in it. See `--bare` and `--mirror` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone.

Comment: All though it only has the .git files and not the actual source code, if you perform a remote update it will re-fetch everything from the origin to the destination.

Comment: This was a lifesaver! This "master before mirror" method fixed issue with Bitbucket being the destination and believing a different branch other than "master" was the main branch.

Comment: This did not work for me for some reason... Maybe because my repository was private.
Anyways I found more info here: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository
and used the step, which is pretty much the same and it worked.
Just FYI, had made my source and target, public.

Comment: @jmmut It is very simple to convert mirror repo to normal repo, one change in config and git reset --hard. https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637378/11173412

Answer (score 34):

Including the + in the push spec is probably a bad idea, as it means that git will happily do a non-fast-forward push *even without -f*, and if the remote server is set up to accept those, you can lose history.

Try just this:

```
$ git config --add remote.origin.push 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
$ git config --add remote.origin.push 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
$ git config --add remote.origin.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
$ git config --add remote.origin.fetch 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```

Comment: You can also add the `--global` option to each of these to make this the global default for all your repositories.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the + is added automatically by git when doing `git remote add`.

Answer (score 16):

If you are moving branches to a new repo from an old one and do NOT have all the old repo branches local, you will need to track them first.

```
for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v '\->'`; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

Then add your new remote repo:

```
git remote add bb <path-to-new-repo>
```

Then you can push all using this command:

```
git push -u bb --all
```

Or you can configure the repo using the git config commands noted in the other responses here if you are not doing this one time or are only looking to move local branches.

The important point, the other responses only push all LOCAL branches.   If the branches only exist on an alternate REMOTE repository they will not move without tracking them first.  The for loop presented here will help with that.

Comment: BTW, I am using "bb" in place of "origin" here because I assume your original/old repository was named "origin" and is likely still attached to that label.   "bb" is for Bitbucket, where I moved my original repo to, but you can call it something more applicable like "neworigin" if you prefer.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Ended up with all remote branches tracking  the same local branch :/

Comment: AFAIK this shouldn't work, as per @jhsowter comment. the right command for me to track a remote branch in a newly cloned repo is `git branch --track reponame origin/reponame` otherwise you'll get all the remote branches tracked on the current local branch

Comment: I changed the repo-collecting snippet to `git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | sed 's/  origin\///'`, which gives just the remote branch name.

Answer (score 11):

If you are moving all branches to a new repo from an old one then in your local repo you need to set up tracking of each branch to existing origin branches, before pushing to the new repo, otherwise **all** your origin branches won’t appear in the new origin. Do this manually by tracking or checking out each branch, or use the one liner:

```
for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | grep -v master`; do git branch --track `echo $remote|sed 's=origin/=='` `echo $remote`; done
```

This one line command is based on versions of it in other answers on this page, but is arguably better because:

1. it correctly sets up the branch tracking, unlike some older variants of this command on this page which only supply one parameter to --track and thus each branch ends up tracking master - not good
2. names the local branches without the prefix “origin/” which I personally don’t want - and is consistent with what happens when you checkout a branch normally.
3. skips tracking master since that is already happening
4. doesn’t actually checkout anything thus is fast
5. avoids stumbling over the -> in the output of git branch -r

Next, if you are switching origins, replace the link to the old origin and point to a new remote.  Ensure you create the new remote first, using bitbucket/github GUI, but don’t add any files to it or there will be a merge problem. E.g.

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:YOUR/SOMEREPO.git
```

Now push.  Note the second command is needed to push the tags as well:

```
git push -u --all origin
git push --tags origin
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the best and simplest method [here](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/git-push-all-branches-new-remote), just as @kumarahul posted, works like a charm for me, it will push all the tags and branches from origin to the new remote:

```
git remote add newremote new-remote-url

git push newremote --tags refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

I used 'git push --all -u newremote', but it only push the checkouted branches to the newremote.

> Git: Push All Branches to a New Remote
>
> by Keith Dechant , Software Architect
>
> Here's a scenario some of you might have encountered with your Git
> repositories. You have a working copy of a Git repo, say from an old
> server. But you only have the working copy, and the origin is not
> accessible. So you can't just fork it. But you want to push the whole
> repo and all the branch history to your new remote.
>
> This is possible if your working copy contains the tracking branches
> from the old remote (origin/branch1, origin/branch1, etc.). If you do,
> you have the entire repo and history.
>
> However, in my case there were dozens of branches, and some or all of
> them I had never checked out locally. Pushing them all seemed like a
> heavy lift. So, how to proceed?
>
> I identified two options:
>
> Option 1: Checkout every branch and push I could do this, and I could
> even write a Bash script to help. However, doing this would change my
> working files with each checkout, and would create a local branch for
> each of the remote tracking branches. This would be slow with a large
> repo.
>
> Option 2: Push without changing your working copy There is a second
> alternative, which doesn't require a checkout of each branch, doesn't
> create extraneous branches in the working copy, and doesn't even
> modify the files in the working copy.
>
> If your old, no-longer-active remote is called "oldremote" and your
> new remote is called "newremote", you can push just the remote
> tracking branches with this command:
>
> `git push newremote refs/remotes/oldremote/*:refs/heads/*`
>
> In some
> cases, it's also possible to push just a subset of the branches. If
> the branch names are namespaced with a slash (e.g.,
> oldremote/features/branch3, oldremote/features/branch4, etc.), you can
> push only the remote tracking branches with names beginning with
> "oldremote/features":
>
> `git push newremote refs/remotes/oldremote/features/*:refs/heads/features/*`
>
> Whether you
> push all the branches or just some of them, Git will perform the
> entire operation without creating any new local branches, and without
> making changes to your working files. Every tracking branch that
> matches your pattern will be pushed to the new remote.
>
> For more information on the topic, check out this thread on Stack
> Overflow.
>
> Date posted: October 9, 2017

Answer (score 7):

To see all the branches with out using `git branch -a` you should execute:

```
for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track $remote; done
git fetch --all
git pull --all
```

Now you can see all the branches:

```
git branch
```

To push all the branches try:

```
git push --all
```

Comment: λ git fetch --all origin
fatal: fetch --all does not take a repository argument

Comment: are you trying `git fetch --all` ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are pushing from one remote origin to another, you can use this:

```
git push newremote refs/remotes/oldremote/*:refs/heads/*
```

This worked for me. Reffer to this: https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/git-push-all-branches-new-remote

Answer (score 4):

The full procedure that worked for me to transfer **ALL** branches and tags is, combining the answers of @vikas027 and @kumarahul:

```
~$ git clone <url_of_old_repo>
~$ cd <name_of_old_repo>
~$ git remote add new-origin <url_of_new_repo>
~$ git push new-origin --mirror
~$ git push new-origin refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
~$ git push new-origin --delete HEAD
```

The last step is because a branch named `HEAD` appears in the new remote due to the wildcard

Answer (score 1):

## Solution without hardcoding `origin` in config

Use the following in your **global** gitconfig

```
[remote]
    push = +refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*
```

This pushes all branches and all tags

### Why should you NOT hardcode `origin` in config?

If you hardcode:

1. You'll end up with `origin` as a remote in all repos. So you'll not be able to add origin, but you need to use `set-url`.
2. If a tool creates a remote with a different name push all config will not apply. Then you'll have to rename the remote, but rename will not work because `origin` already exists (from point 1) remember :)

### Fetching is taken care of already by modern git

As per Jakub Narębski's answer:

> With modern git you always fetch all branches (as remote-tracking branches into refs/remotes/origin/* namespace

Answer (score 1):

Add your new remote repo and the last step will exclude the HEAD branch when you push

```sh
git clone <url_of_old_repo>
cd <name_of_old_repo>
git remote add new-origin <url_of_new_repo>
git ls-remote . | grep 'refs/remotes/origin/' | grep -v 'HEAD' | awk -F 'origin/' '{print $2}' | xargs -i git push -f new-origin  --tags refs/remotes/origin/{}:refs/heads/{}
```

Answer (score 0):

first add the remote git to your loacl with

```
git remote add remote_name remote_address
```

and after you just need to do it with the following command

```
git push --all remote_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The [2012 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10479068/6309) mentions `git push --all origin` as "This will push tags and branches."

Well... no: it will [push only all branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all) (i.e. refs under `refs/heads/`, *not* under `refs/tags/`)

That is why in 2023, with Git 2.41, the answer to "Set up git to pull and push all branches" would be:

```
git push -u --branches
```

Because with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git push --all`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f37da977232ff490343d480dfbcd6afcc4d5523e/Documentation/git-push.txt#L149)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all))</sup> gained an **alias** [`git push  --branches`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f37da977232ff490343d480dfbcd6afcc4d5523e/Documentation/git-push.txt#L149-L152)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all))</sup>".

See [commit 022fbb6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/022fbb655d371db6382415bcfba5cdf741afeb41) (12 May 2023) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 425b4d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/425b4d7f47bd2be561ced14eac36056390862e8c) (06 May 2023) by [Teng Long (`dyrone`)](https://github.com/dyrone).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f37da97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f37da977232ff490343d480dfbcd6afcc4d5523e), 15 May 2023)</sup>

> ### [`push`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/425b4d7f47bd2be561ced14eac36056390862e8c): introduce '--branches' option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Teng Long</sup>

> The '`--all`' option of [`git-push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/425b4d7f47bd2be561ced14eac36056390862e8c/Documentation/git-push.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> built-in cmd support to push all branches (refs under refs/heads) to remote.
> Under the usage, a user can easlily work in some scenarios, for example, branches synchronization and batch upload.
>
> The '`--all`' was introduced for a long time, meanwhile, git supports to customize the storage location under `refs/`".
> When a new Git user see the usage like, '`git push origin --all`', we might feel like we're pushing *all* the refs instead of just branches without looking at the documents until we found the related description of it or '`--mirror`'.
>
> To ensure compatibility, we cannot rename '`--all`' to another name directly, one way is, we can try to add a new option '`--heads`' which be identical with the functionality of '`--all`' to let the user understand the meaning of representation more clearly.
> Actually, We've more or less named options this way already, for example, in '`git-show-ref`' and '[`git ls-remote`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/425b4d7f47bd2be561ced14eac36056390862e8c/Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote))</sup>.

`git push` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/425b4d7f47bd2be561ced14eac36056390862e8c/Documentation/git-push.txt#L12):

> `'git push' [--all | --branches | --mirror | --tags] [--follow-tags] [--atomic] [-n | --dry-run] [--receive-pack=<git-receive-pack>]`

`git push` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/425b4d7f47bd2be561ced14eac36056390862e8c/Documentation/git-push.txt#L150):

> ### `--branches`