# With GitHub how do I push all branches when adding an existing repo?

Tags: git, github

I created a new GitHub repo - I want to put my existing repo there.
I followed the instructions:

```
cd existing_git_repo
git remote add origin git@github.com:acme-org/myprj.git
git push origin master
```

This only pushes the master branch to GitHub.
How do I push everything (including all branches) in my existing repo to my new GitHub repo?

Comment: Note: you also have `git push --follow-tags` with git 1.8.3+ (May 2013). See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4886153/6309)

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Note: git push --all won't push your tags, only your branches.

```
git push --all
git push --tags
```

would really push *everything*. See also "[Set up git to pull and push all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches)".
Don't forget the **`--dry-run`** option to make some test before actually pushing everything.
See also GitHub help "[Working with remotes](http://help.github.com/remotes/)" to set your origin to your GitHub remote repo.

---

As mentioned in "[How to make “git push” include tags within a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219399/6309)", git 1.8.3+ (May 2013) introduced:

```
git push --follow-tags
```

> This won't push all the tags, but only the ones accessible from the branch(es) HEAD(s) you are pushing.

That can help keeping that operation (pushing commits *and* tags) done with *one* command instead of two.

Git 2.4.1+ (Q2 2015) will introduce the option `push.followTags`.

Comment: This appears not to work when you want to push to another remote (instead of origin), it only pushes my current branch.

Comment: @Aloys that would depend on your git version and current default push policy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002239/difference-between-git-checkout-track-origin-branch-and-git-checkout-b-branch/10002469#10002469

Comment: If you want to push remote branches as well use `--mirror`

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer isn't quite right, or at least it didn't work for me.  I needed to specify the remote repo as well, eg:

```
git push origin --all
```

Comment: Specifying the remote is only necessary when upstream is unset.

Comment: repository required if multiple remotes have been added, I believe  (`$git remote -v`)

Comment: To set tracking between the local and remote branchs -u can be added: `git push -u origin --all`