# Initialize gitolite repository in existing folder

Tags: git, terminal, gitolite

I'm fairly new to Git and Gitolite, but yesterday I managed to get it up and running.

The thing is, I have a folder with many projects (let's call it `/projects`) and I'm trying to migrate them to Git. I symlinked Gitolites `/repositories` folder to this `/projects` folder, so now every new repo is created in the `/projects` folder. It works allright.

But now I want to make a repo for every project (subfolder) in the `/projects` folder. If I initialize a new repo in Gitolite (let's call it `/myproject`), it creates a new folder called `myproject.git` instead of using the old `myproject` folder with the files I'm already working with.

So, how can I turn all the individual projects folders into Git repositories, using Gitolite? I'd like not to manually download and append all those files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the way [Gitolite works](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/45755883/ns/msnbc-the_last_word/#50594835): it manages *bare* repositories (the `xxx.git` folders), not working tree (directories full of files, like `projects/myprojects/`).

So: don't symlink repositories to /projects: both are for very different purpose.

You can inititiate and import each project directly in their own directory (`/projects/myproject/.git`), and then import it to Gitolite, following "[how to configure a migrated git repository in gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10345296/6309)".

---

[Pierre De LESPINAY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305189/pierre-de-lespinay) mention[s in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589162/initialize-gitolite-repository-in-existing-folder/14589805?noredirect=1#comment39952240_14589805) the official documentation:

### "[appendix 1: bringing existing repos into gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin.html#existing)"

> - Move the repos to `$HOME/repositories`.
> - Make sure that:
>
>   - They are all bare repos.
>   - All the repo names end in "`.git`".
>   - All the files and directories are owned and writable by the gitolite hosting user (especially true if you copied them as root).
> - Run **`gitolite setup`**.
>     If you forget this step, you can also forget about write access control!
>
> back on your workstation:
>
> - If the repos are normal repos, add them to `conf/gitolite.conf` in your clone of the admin repo, then commit and push the change.
> - If the repos are wildcard repos that already match some repo regex in the conf file, you need to manually create the gl-creator file, like so:

```
echo username > ~/repositories/path/to/repo.git/gl-creator
```

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, Gitolite won't manage my project's files, as a standard Git repo would?

Comment: @ArminCifuentes Gitolite is an **[authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html)**: all it does is accept or deny your git clone/push/pull commands to said `repositories/`: for that, not need of a full repos, only a **[bare repo](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html)** is enough.

Comment: The official instructions for [bringing existing repos into gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin.html#existing) worked fine for me

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY good point. I have included those instructions in the answer for more visibility.