# Run git commands on remote working tree (GIT_WORK_TREE=/path)

Tags: git

I have a bare git repo set up which runs a post-update hook as follows:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/code git checkout -f
```

This works well when pushing code to, for example, a webserver. I can work on code, and when I'm finished, updating the webserver is a simple `git push live master` away.

However, I don't know how to rollback to, for example, a specific tag. Usually that can be done with `git checkout TAG`, but when I attempt to checkout a tag (e.g. `GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/code git checkout -f TAG`), git responds:

```
error: pathspec 'TAG' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Any ideas on how to checkout a tag on a remote working tree?

Comment: Did you pushed that tag? git push --tags

Comment: I pushed the master branch - don't tags "tag along" with a push?

Comment: Apparently not. I just pushed the tags, and I've got a lot more choices for `checkout`! If you provide an answer below, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To checkout a tag on the remote side, you need to push it first:

```
git push --tags
```

As mentioned in "[With GitHub how do I push all branches when adding an existing repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886153/6309)", even `git push --all` wouldn't push your tags, only all refs under `refs/heads/`.