# Is it possible to get git to automatically update notes on the remote server when I do a git push/git pull

Tags: git, git-notes

Currently if I add notes to an object in git I have to explicitly push/pull this information to the remote server.

Is it possible to configure git so that when I do a `git push` it will push my local notes changes as well as any local source changes?

Likewise for git pull.

Answer (score 4):

Yes for `git pull`, no for `git push`.

You can fetch notes:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

but, as mentioned in "[Note to Self](http://scottchacon.com/2010/08/25/notes.html)" (2010, but I don't think this has changed):

> However, you can push anything under '`refs/`' to a server, you just need to be more explicit about it. If you run this it will work fine:

```
$ git push origin refs/notes/bugzilla
```

> In fact, you may want to just make that `git push origin refs/notes/*` which will push all your notes.
>   This is [what Git does normally for something like tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15282345/6309). When you run `git push origin --tags` it basically expands to `git push origin refs/tags/*`.

`git push` doesn't push all tags by default (see "[Why git doesn't push tags by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16830402/6309)").
`git push` doesn't push all notes for the same reason.

Comment: However "you *can*" not "can't"

Comment: I found a way to do it btw. Mostly. The downside is that you get behaviour like `push.default = current` as a side-effect, instead of the nice, upstream-aware `push.simple`. I'd love your advice on if there's something I'm missing to take it that next step, or if it's submit-a-patch time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53003190/398670

Answer (score 3):

### You can auto-push notes, but it changes default push

Yes, you can configure a remote to push multiple branches and additional branches.

It comes at the cost of overriding the default "push current branch" behaviour defined by `push.default = 'simple'`, making it behave like `current` instead; it pushes to a branch with the same name as the upstream and ignores any `git branch --set-upstream-to` that's been configured.

Assuming your remote is `origin` then:

```
git config --unset-all remote.origin.push
git config --add remote.origin.push "HEAD"
git config --add remote.origin.push "refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits"
```

### Push notes and push branch to upstream-tracking branch

We *should* be able to achieve behaviour like `push.default = upstream` with something like:

```
# THIS WON'T WORK
git config --unset-all remote.origin.push
git config --add remote.origin.push "HEAD:@{upstream}"
git config --add remote.origin.push "refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits"
```

instead.

But it doesn't work on my git 2.17.1, failing with:

```
fatal: Invalid refspec 'HEAD:@{upstream}'
```

even though I see documentation talking about using `@{upstream}` in push refspecs. You can

```
git push origin "@{upstream}"
```

and you'll get a complaint like

```
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in @{upstream}
```

because git resolves it to a refspec `@{upstream}:@{upstream}`, doesn't resolve `@{upstream}` to anything on the remote-side, and complains. This is distinct from its behaviour when pushing `HEAD` where it automagically uses the branch-name as the upstream.

Unfortunate. But you could argue `@{upstream}` doesn't make sense on the remote side.

### Wishlist: simple plus extra refspecs

What we really *want* to be able to do is add *extra* refspecs and leave the `push.default` behaviour alone.

But git doesn't understand `push.default` names in `remote.*.push` settings - it couldn't tell them apart from branch names, after all.

It also doesn't seem to have a way to say "use this remotes.origin.push config to ADD to the default refspec list".

I want something like this imaginary non-working config:

```
# THIS WON'T WORK
git config --add remote.origin.push "{DEFAULT}"
git config --add remote.origin.push "refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits"
```

or

```
# THIS WON'T WORK
git config remote.origin.push_default "simple"
git config --add remote.origin.push "refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits"
```

or

```
# THIS WON'T WORK
git config remote.origin.push @{simple}
git config --add remote.origin.push "refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits"
```

You have to use an explicit refspec like `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` (always push master) or (DANGER) `refs/heads/*`

And there doesn't seem to be a way to encode the "simple" behaviour of "push to configured upstream origin, refuse if there isn't one" into the remote-side of a refspec.

## Testing

I *very strongly recommend* that you first

```
git push --verbose --dry-run --porcelain origin
```

before you do anything for real. The `--porcelain` disables the summary's "helpful" habit of simplifying `refs/heads` in ways that make them ambiguous if you've made a mistake in your config.

Also, be aware that you will have disabled git's default protection against accidentally pushing a branch that doesn't correspond to an upstream of the same name.

Overall, I recommend not doing it.

## See also

- "--refspec" in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec
- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions
- https://git.seveas.net/the-meaning-of-refs-and-refspecs.html
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/refs-and-the-reflog

Comment: AFAICS yes, still in place

Comment: Has anything changed in 2020?