# how do I make git push all tracking branches?

Tags: git

Is there a way to get git push to push all branches which are already set to be tracking?

For example, suppose I have three branches which track remotely: dev, staging, and production. I make commits and merges and now wish to push all three. Is there a single command to do this?

(Note: not the same as [With GitHub how do I push all branches when adding an existing repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885999/with-github-how-do-i-push-all-branches-when-adding-an-existing-repo) and git push --all won't work, as it will push all local branches, not just tracking ones.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/498699 Please see this question and answer

Comment: please add an example. probably if your case is not an option in `push.default` you have to script it yourself.

Comment: Well for example, suppose that I have a project with three branches which are tracking: master, staging, and dev. I also have a bunch of local branches for local work only. I make various commits and merges, and I want master, staging, and dev to all push to the remote repository. How can I do that in a single short command?