# pushed git repository missing branch & tag names on gitk

Tags: git, git-push, git-branch, git-tag

I just did my first ever `git push`:

```
~/sb/ws> git push ~/gitrepo master:master
Counting objects: 1360, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (998/998), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1360/1360), 342.15 KiB | 20 KiB/s, done.
Total 1360 (delta 729), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /home/gitrepo
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

It seems to have gone well, but when fire `gitk` in the new (bare) gitrepo, I only see the commit comments: The branch & tag names disappeared!

Why?

Is there a way to get them back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To push the tags, you need to add `--tags` to your push.

By default you only pushed the master branch.
To push individual branches (with tags) do `git push ~/gitrepo branchname --tags`
To push all branches do `git push --all`.  Do a **separate** `git push --tags` if you want to push all tags.

Here's [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches/1915046#1915046) on how to default to pushing all branches.

edit: Added info from Winwin's comments

Comment: Thanks +1. If I do `git push --all --tags ~/gitrepo` I receive: `error: --all and --tags are incompatible`, so I understand that pushing all branches *and* all tags in one command is not possible?

Comment: `git push --all  ~/gitrepo` works great. Now I need to see how to add the tags.

Comment: `git push --tags ~/gitrepo` **adds** all the tags. Nice!

Comment: I honestly have never tried it, but it would appear that that is the case. [link](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=577935)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a separate push with the --tags option. Secondly, you should be calling gitk with the --all option to show all branches. Or you could just specify the ones you want.

Comment: yup. they are! But you should also not push all tags and specify the tag you want to push.