# Listing all remote branches with multiple remotes

Tags: git

We have a gitolite server setup and running for use within our team. The parent for my local git repository is a central svn repo. The gitolite server has been added as a remote and I am able to push and pull from it. Everything works fine except that I cannot see the branches that are created on the remote server even after I do

```
git remote update
```

I checked the .git/config file and I see that the tracking is set up as

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@server:project
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

If I manually change this to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@server:project
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

then I can see all remote branches also on origin.

My question is, is it possible for me to ask git to track everything on remote when I add it? If not, are these manual changes safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the modifications are safe, and you can even add more of those rules: see [Set up git to pull and push all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches) (for tags and for push).

If you want to track all branches from remote, you can refer to [this one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309) from the question "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches)".
That will modify or create the config of each local branches in order for them to track their remote counterpart.