# How do I recover git pruned remote branches?

Tags: git

For remote branches that have been removed via `git prune --all origin`, how do you restore them?

#### Assumption

There are over 100 branches and shared by a team of 20 people and everyone is working on different sets of branches.

Comment: That command doesn't seem to be valid. `git prune` doesn't have a `--all` option and it doesn't take a remote as an argument (although that could be a ref name. If it was meant to be `git fetch --prune --all origin`, that would seem a bit closer; but `--all` doesn't work if a remote is specified.

Comment: I might have forgotten the exact syntax, but bottom line is a bunch of remote branches have been annihilated and what's the best way to recover them, short of pushing each branch back to it again?

Comment: From which end are the branches missing, the local repository or the remote one?

Comment: Local and remote for the person who committed this.

Answer (score 2):

Pushing all branches back again seems the easiest solution (as in "[Set up git to pull and push all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches)")
(unless you find those branches still referenced in the reflog of the server)

Then you can make sure your local repo is tracking them again, with that one-liner in "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309)".