# git push.default include current new branch

Tags: git

Suppose I just created a local branch `b`.
When I do `git push` it pushes changes from other branches according to matching (git 1.x default):

> push all branches having the same name on both ends. This makes the repository you are pushing to remember the set of branches that will be pushed out (e.g. if you always push maint and master there and no other branches, the repository you push to will have these two branches, and your local maint and master will be pushed there).

However, if the current branch doesn't exist on the remote yet, it will not push the current branch.  `git push --all` seems to do this.  Is there a way to make this behavior default for `git push`?  Are there any bad side-effects to aliasing `push=push --all`?

Edit: actually I only want it to push matching + current branch (including new), excluding other new branches

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by

```
git config --add remote.origin.push 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5239626/1497059

**Update:**

If you only want to push the current *new* branch, you can use the `push.default=current` setting:

```
git config --add push.default current
```

Comment: Upvote! I also just edited my question a bit since I realized I only want to push new branch if it's the current branch.  Do you know if that's possible?