# stop git push from pushing to multiple branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

I created a new branch (`tags`), checked it out, and whenever I push changes I use `git push origin tags`. However, the pushed changes are effecting both the `master` branch and the `tags` branch in my remote repo.

I'm sure I've got the `tags` branch checked out (verified with `git status`). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm a git newbie and so I'm not sure what I might need to include in this post to help with the diagnosis, let me know if I should include something specific.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you have may have something fishy going on with you Git config (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1915046)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, except "`tags`" is not the best name for a branch name.

When you push tags, it will add to `origin/tags`, not `origin/master`.

The best practice would be:

```
git push -u origin tags
```

That would link the local branch to it upstream one `origin/tags`.
See the output of `git branch -avv`.

And if you checkout `master`, you will see that the commits done in branch `tags` are no longer there.