# Git history not showing

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, github-api

I am trying to migrate my git repository from AWS to GCP.

I am following these steps:

```
git clone --mirror URL
git remote add NEW-REMOTE URL
git push  NEW-REMOTE --mirror 
git remote rm origin
git remote rename NEW-REMOTE origin
```

So whenever I open the GCP console source repository, it is only showing the commit history of the master.

I want to migrate my whole repository with all the history and tags to GCP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to push all branches the NEW-REMOTE?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes i want to push all branches along with commit history.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches?

Comment: everything up to date but no history data in GCP.

Comment: If everything is up-to-date, then there is history in GCP. The next step is to figure out why you can't see it.

Comment: okay sure let me check aain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP does not show the branch history when you change the branch from panel.

GCP shows it in a different manner, as change history.

When you click on any file, then you can see all the file change history from the change history panel in GCP.