# In Git, can I "Checkout" all remote branches in my local repo?

Tags: git, gitlab

We recreated our Gitlab server and I was pushing the branches I had checked out. I then noticed that I could still checkout all of the other branches in the repo that I had never touched. However when I tried to push all branches to the new Gitlab server, it only pushed the branches that I had checked out, not all the branches listed. Is there a way to checkout all of the branches or to push these branches to the server?

Comment: possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches#10479068

Answer (score 1):

> I then noticed that I could still checkout all of the other branches in the repo that I had never touched ...

For a proper, thorough answer, we need to note two things:

1. `git checkout` can check out a branch.  No surprise here (well, not yet).  When you do this, Git checks out the branch.  This involves checking out one specific commit, but also putting you "on" the branch, so that `git status` says, e.g., `on branch master`.
2. `git checkout` can *also* check out things that are *not* branches.  When you use `git checkout v2.1` (where `v2.1` is a tag name), for instance, Git checks out one specific commit, and calls that a *detached HEAD*.

   When you are in this detached HEAD mode, you are not on *any* branch.  As we'll see in a moment, this detached HEAD thing also applies to other non-branch-name items, including *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`.

What we really need here is a good, solid definition of the word *branch*.  Unfortunately, in Git, there are multiple conflicting definitions, depending on how you like to use the word.  (For more about this, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

The meaning we're using in item 1 above is a *branch name*, which some people call a *local branch*.  These are names like `master` or `develop` (vs `origin/master` and `origin/develop`).  A branch name like these two—which are actually just shorthand for a longer form, `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/develop` here—has two important properties:

- it contains the hash ID of one commit, and
- Git will *automatically update* the hash ID stored in that name under various conditions.  In particular, when *you* make a new commit while "on" one of your branches, Git will store the *new* commit's hash ID into the branch name.

These branch names exist in your repository and are quite independent of any branch names that may or may not exist in any other repository.

Names like `origin/master` and `origin/develop` are not exactly *branch* names, though some people like to call them branch names.<sup>1</sup>  (This is where the rather wobbly definitions that Git and Git-users use cause issues.)  They obey the first rule—they point to one particular commit—but not the second.<sup>2</sup>  You can run `git checkout origin/master`, but as with the tag `v2.1`, you wind up with a detached HEAD.  You're not on *any* branch.

So this *could* be the whole answer:

1. `git checkout branch` checks out a (local) branch that you already have, and
2. `git checkout remote-tracking-name` checks out the commit identified by a remote-tracking name.

But it's not the whole answer, because `git checkout` can *create* a branch for you.<sup>3</sup>  Suppose that you *don't* have a local branch named `develop`, but *do* have a remote-tracking name `origin/develop`.  Running:

```
git checkout develop
```

will typically succeed, and will work by first *creating* a (local) `develop` using `origin/develop` to set both its upstream and its current commit hash ID.<sup>4</sup>  That is, Git will first look for the existing branch name `develop`.  If that does exist, Git will (try to<sup>5</sup>) check out that branch, and be done.  But if *not*, rather than immediately failing, Git will poke around to see if you have a *remote-tracking name* that looks similar, such as `origin/develop`.  If so, checkout uses what Git calls *DWIM*—Do What I Mean—to turn this into `git checkout -b develop origin/develop`.

So to the two above, we must add:

3. `git checkout name-that-does-not-yet-exist` will, if it can, *create* a branch and check it out.  The "DWIM" feature finds a remote-tracking name to use as a guide and creates the branch and checks it out.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that remote-tracking names `origin/master` and `origin/develop` are also shortened forms, for `refs/remotes/origin/master` and `refs/remotes/origin/develop` respectively.  If you ever accidentally create a *local* branch named `origin/X`, its full name is `refs/heads/origin/X` and that's what makes it a local branch.  You should rename or remove it quickly, though, because Git will shorten it to `origin/X` and that may well confuse you, especially if you also have a `refs/remotes/origin/X`, which Git will *also* shorten to `origin/X`.

<sup>2</sup>Git *does* update remote-tracking names, but it does so when you run `git fetch`.  Your Git calls up some *other* Git—the one over at `origin`, for instance—and asks *that* Git which commit each of *its* branch names, `master` and `develop` in this case, identifies.  Your Git then gets those commits if needed.  If you already have those commits, your Git gets to skip this step.  Then, with the commits locally available in *your* repository, your Git now creates or updates your remote-tracking names corresponding to the branch names in the other Git.

Since you can't be "on" a remote-tracking name, updating those names at `git fetch` time is safe.

<sup>3</sup>In fact, it has a lot of create-a-branch modes, using `git checkout -b`, `git checkout -B`, `git checkout --track`, and so on.  But here we're looking only at what Git calls "DWIM".

<sup>4</sup>Some of this is configurable.  The description here covers only the default actions, to keep this answer from being even longer.

<sup>5</sup>`git checkout` will sometimes fail with an error, in which case it should have left everything alone.  The error message is meant to tell you why it did nothing.

---

#### Conclusion

Besides checking out a local branch in the usual way, there are *two* ways that you can `git checkout` "remote branches"—whatever you may mean by "remote branches"—because you can either use detached HEAD mode to check out, and thus inspect, `origin/foo`, or you can use DWIM mode to create a local `foo` using `origin/foo`, and check that out as a local branch in the usual way.

If you *do* use DWIM mode, you accumulate a bunch of new local branches.  Once you have done that, those are *your* branch names.  They will not automatically update when something happens in the *other* Git!  They will only update when you are "on" them and do something that updates them.

Answer (score 1):

here's a one-liner I ended up using:

```
remote="origin\/"; for branch in $(git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v HEAD | sed "s/$remote//"); do echo $branch; git checkout $branch; done
```

breakdown:

- define the remote wanted. I needed this because this repo had multiple ones. On this step we include an escaped slash;
- loop through every branch;
- use `grep` to narrow down to the branches we want. In this case we use the `$remote` defined earlier and 'HEAD' to remove 'remote/HEAD' from the options;
- use `sed` to remove the remote name and the slash from the options;
- finally we can checkout every branch

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
git branch -r
```

then you can see remote branches. If you put all of those into a file and then put

```
git checkout
```

as a prefix (with vim this is very easy to do) for all records and then run your file in the command-line, then it should `checkout` all the branches.

Comment: Thank you for your very concise answer. It is not 100% but it sent me down the right path. The command needed was git checkout -b {branch name with origin/ trimmed} {branch name with remotes/ added at the beginning}
This creates a new branch instead of being detached and has it attached to the remote branch