# How to get a full repo copy with git

Tags: git

I cloned a remote repo and want to have a own copy on my local git server.

So I did:

```
git clone ssh...
```

I created a new repo on my server

```
git init --bare
```

I added the new server

```
git remote add bm ssh...
```

Than I pushed to the new remote

```
git push --mirror bm
```

Now I can see on my bare server repo:

```
[gitmini@blaumeise simulavr]$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/bm/master
  remotes/savannah/HEAD
  remotes/savannah/devel-tomk
  remotes/savannah/master
  remotes/savannah/oldstable
  remotes/savannah/python_3
  remotes/savannah/rel-1.0
  remotes/savannah/rel-1.1
  remotes/savannah/sbi_cbi_rework
```

Looks good I think.

But now I checked out from my local server

```
  git clone ssh...
```

and I only get:

```
  git branch -a

[krud@blaumeise simulavr]$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I already did: `git fetch --all` and `git pull --all`, nothing changed.

Is there something wrong with my own server repo or something wrong while clone? What can I do in such a bad situation.

I already read: [How to fetch all Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches)

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you linked tells you how to set up to track all remote branches.  Is that not what you want?  If not, how is what you want different?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Sorry, you are right! The important point is to use the add on from the answer from Kamil Szot's . The first "solution" ends up in a long list of duplicate of branches. Using Kamil solution seems to work perfect!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up git to pull and push all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clone` defaults to copying only the (local) branches and tags of the other Git.  You *can* get additional references, including remote-tracking names like `remotes/savannah/oldstable`.  But that's usually not a good idea.  Instead, in your bare repository, make *it* have *branches* with these names.

This is all a little bit tricky at first, but eventually it all starts to make sense.  These names arise from the use of two separate Git repositories.  Each Git repository has *its own* branch names, so:

- A *branch name* is a reference whose full name starts with `refs/heads/`.  So `refs/heads/master` represents branch `master`, and so on.
- A *remote-tracking name* is a reference whose full name starts with `refs/remotes/`.  The next part of the full name is the same as the name of the *remote*, and after that (and another slash) you get the *branch name* taken from the other Git.

This is the normal usage pattern for normal clones.  There's some existing repository, which someone—or many someones—have set up somewhere out on the web (perhaps on GitHub, for instance), and it has a bunch of branches: `master`, `develop`, `feature/A`, `feature/B`, and so on.  You clone that repository to your own machine (laptop or whatever) and would like to have your Git remember *their* branches for you, but not *create* a bunch of (local) branches.  You now choose, perhaps, to do some work that you want to send to them later as a part of `feature/A`, so you create *your own* name `feature/A` on which to make new commits to send to them and recommend that they put those in *their* `feature/A`.  You're not working on `feature/B` at all, so you don't get a `feature/B`, and you're not using `master` so you can delete your own `master`.

Once you *do* have some new commits, you will use:

```
git push origin feature/A
```

to send your new commits to their Git, and immediately—as part of `git push` itself—ask *their* Git to set *their* `feature/A` branch to remember those new commits.

#### That's not what you want here

When you're first setting up centralized server repository, you often *don't want* to follow the normal pattern.  You have—or would like to copy—some existing repository that has, say, a dozen branch names.  If this repository *isn't* on your own laptop yet, you can use `git clone --mirror` to make a temporary copy on your own laptop:

```
git clone --mirror <url> [<path>]
```

Now you have, on your laptop, a bare clone (`--mirror` implies `--bare`) that has *no* `origin/*` remote-tracking names at all.  Instead, Git has created, in your copy of their repository, regular old branch names—not remote-tracking names—corresponding to their branch names.  So you have the *same* dozen branch names that they have.

**A mirror clone is useless for doing any work of your own!**  You create this mirror clone *temporarily*, to get a copy of their repository in which *their branch names are your branch names too*.  If you already have a full working repository with your dozen (or whatever) branches, you *skip* this step.

Now that you have the clone that has all the branches, *now* you can create an empty repository on the server (or on GitHub).  *Now* you can run:

```
git push --all <url-of-server-repository>
```

And now, if you made a mirror clone, you can *throw away* the mirror clone.  You made it only for the purpose of sending everything, including all the branch names, to the server.  So now you might like to remove the mirror clone *and* make a normal clone of the server clone to use to do actual work.

(If you did a `git push` from a local repository that was already all set, you don't want or need to remove the local clone, and you might want to use `git remote add` before the `git push`.  See below.)

#### The above is somewhat wasteful!

You might object to having to make this silly mirror clone, only to then have to throw it out and make a normal, non-bare clone after pushing the mirror clone to the server.

You **do not have to make the mirror clone**.  This is only for convenience.

Instead, you can:

- make a regular clone
- create *local* branches as needed to represent all the remote-tracking names
- use `git push --all` to send these all to the server
- *remove* all the local names you made (but keep any you didn't have to make).

Or, instead of the above, you can:

- make (or have) a regular clone
- use `git push` without `--all`: instead, use *refspecs* to push the *remote-tracking names* on your end to *branch names* on their end.

This last method is in some ways the neatest, but it requires understanding refspecs.

A refspec is, in its second-simplest form, a pair of references—full names like `refs/heads/master` or `refs/remotes/feature/A`—separated by a colon `:`.  The name on the left side of the colon is the *source* and the name on the right side is the *destination*.  Refspecs behave similarly, though not identically, in both `git fetch` and `git push`: the *source* ref provides a commit hash in the sending Git, and the destination ref provides a *name* to set in the *receiving* Git.  Since `git push` sends from *your* Git repository to *their* Git repository, you can use your remote-tracking names on the left, and their branch names on the right:

```
# after creating an empty repository on github
git remote add origin <url-on-github>
git push origin master   # send your refs/heads/master to theirs
git push origin refs/remotes/savannah/devel-tomk:refs/heads/devel-tomk
git push origin refs/remotes/savannah/python_3:refs/heads/python_3
```

(assuming you want your remote-tracking `savannah/devel-tomk` to become their `devel-tomk` branch, and so on).

You can put all the refspecs into one big `git push` line, but it's ridiculously easy to typo part of it, which is annoying:

```
git push origin master refs/remotes/savannah/devel-tomk:refs/heads/devel-tomk refs/remotes/savannah/python_3:refs/heads/python_3
```

for instance, if I did not typo anything.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create a copy of the entire repo. You only created a repo with master branch.

By default push is pushing only a single branch. Try adding the `--all` flag

```
git push --mirror --all bm
```

Comment: results to: fatal: --all and --mirror are incompatible